# React native Expo - Web | Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-web

I've updated my react, expo and expo-cli version recently and am trying to get expo web running on this updated project, but whenever I run `expo start --web` I get the following error:

```
 web  Failed to compile.
/App/App.js
SyntaxError: /App/App.js: Unexpected token (6:9)

  4 | 
  5 | const App = () => {
> 6 |   return <Text>Hii</Text>;
    |          ^
  7 | };
  8 | 
  9 | export default App;
```

The app works fine on IOS and android, but I keep getting this error for web.

Not sure what's causing the error.

I've added `"web"` to `platform` in my `app.json`

**My app file is**

```
import React from "react";

import { Text } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  return <Text>Hii</Text>;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't see setLoading(false) in your file

Comment: @Oyeme Thanks for pointing it out, made a mistake corrected the question!

Comment: Someone resolved this issue? im facing to.